# R: Read in csv, find first line matching pattern

Tags: r, csv

So, I'm working with some software that outputs the data as csv files with the following format:

```
# Parameter 1
ID,Col1,Col2,Col3
1,a,b,c
2,d,e,f
3,g,h,i
[...]
j,x,y,z

# Parameter 2
ID,Col1,Col2,Col3
1,a,b,c
2,d,e,f
3,g,h,i
[...]
k,x,y,z

# Parameter 3
ID,Col1,Col2,Col3
1,a,b,c
2,d,e,f
3,g,h,i
[...]
n,x,y,z
```

If I needed to read in the 10th row of parameter 1, I'd use `read.csv('file.csv', header=FALSE, skip=10, nrows=1)`, and this would give me what I want.  However, if I want to read down to the 10th observation for parameter 2, I don't know what integer to assign skip, due to the variable number of observations in Parameter 1.  I could solve this problem if I could figure out the line number that matches the string `"# Parameter 2"`.  How would I do this?

Comment: Is what you have pasted the literal contents of the file?  If not, that wold be helpful

Comment: No--sorry if that was unclear.  But it was easier to ask the question using this simplified data, and it would be easy enough to extend if I knew how to find the line number that matched a string.

Comment: use `grep` to match strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `readLines`

```
# Assuming that what indicates the
#  start of param2 is the follwing line
param2.indic <- "# Parameter 2"


# read in the raw file
lines <- readLines("path\to\file.csv")

# find the start of parameter 2
p2.start <- grep(param2.indic, lines)

# go down n+2 lines from p2.start
n <- 10  # which line to find
lines[p2.start + n + 2]
```

Comment: Nice!  Is there a way to force grep to return only perfect matches?  For example, if I had another row '# Parameter 2 Meta' and I didn't want that to also match?  I tried setting fixed=TRUE, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect.

Comment: yes, use anchors.  `grep(paste0("^", PATTERN, "$"), string)`     -   Have a look at www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: This is a good answer and got me thinking about other solutions. It would be nice, hoever, if your example code were executable. `param2.indic` and `p2.start` are not good python variables as you write them. I would use `parameter_2 = "# Parameter 2"` and `p2_start = grep(parameter_2, lines)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the lines until you get to the one that matches, and then start from there.

**Example:** I read lines until I get a match. In this case, my file has a long multi-line header that I need to skip, followed by a normal spreadsheet-style csv. I'm looking for the header row, that I know starts with "Sample_ID" as the first element.

```
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in csvreader:
    if row[0].strip() == 'Sample_ID':
        header = row
        break
```

Now that I've queued the row up to the header row, I can process the remainder of the file as I like:

```
sample_ids = []
for row in csvreader:
    sample_ids.append(row[0])
```